# Permissions for Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate my app with Facebook just for posting a message on the user's wall.

So I've downloaded the latest Facebook SDK, then changed one line to force using Facebook Login Dialog instead of safari:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];
```

Now authorization works fine, but after entering credentials it asks for permission to "Access my basic information" and "Post to my Wall" (I've added publish_stream).

I'm worried that users might get scared by the fact that my app is trying to get their info including list of friends, etc.

So my question is: Is it possible to have only "Post to my Wall" in the permission request without "Access my basic information"?

Answer (score 2):

I think I get what you're asking. Can you remove the "Access my basic information" from the step, right?

You can't do this because by default that is what any app gets access to. It's only the basic information (i.e., name, profile information, friends list, etc.). This is similar to the information friends get when a person approves their friend request.

Are you thinking that it's equivalent to accessing all of of their information? The reason I ask is because the request doesn't seem to be a major request.

Btw, to post to their wall you would need some of their basic information, specifically their facebook user ID.

Answer (score -1):

So far, I haven't seen an app that doesn't do that. The problem is that Facebook doesn't trust you. And they're right.

Maybe you should stick to the Safari solution? You can get a link, which you load up in a web view with your customizations specified in the URL (as specified by Facebook).

Comment: I'm not trying to skip step of asking permissions at all. The problem is that my app doesn't need to get any info about user, therefore, I don't want user to be asked to share his info. My app just posts a message on the wall, so what I want to achieve is that in Permissions request it asks only for "Post on my Wall". Is there way to do it?

Comment: With Facebook, it's all or nothing. That's one important downside of the Facebook platform. Users have to trust the app everything. They should implement an entitlement system, like for Lion's sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way you can skip this step. For security reasons, facebook puts this dialog. If this step was not there then we could you developed an app to post spam message on users wall :-)

Comment: I'm not trying to skip step of asking permissions at all. The problem is that my app doesn't need to get any info about user, therefore, I don't want user to be asked to share his info. My app just posts a message on the wall, so what I want to achieve is that in Permissions request it asks only for "Post on my Wall". Is there way to do it?